# Does it save runtime to rename a repeatedly used variable a.b.c as d = a.b.c, or is it equivalent?

Tags: javascript, optimization

Rather than grabbing c's memory location from b, and b's from a as in the title, would it be faster to just store a.b.c's memory location as d? An example will do better than a description for my question.

Say that I have the following javascript code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    object1[index].name.value1 = object2[index].name.value1;
    object1[index].name.value2 = object2[index].name.value2;
    object1[index].name.value3 = object2[index].name.value3;
    object1[index].name.value4 = object2[index].name.value4;
    object1[index].name.value5 = object2[index].name.value5;
}
```

Would it run faster if I changed I saved a reference to object[index].name, or does this run equivalently making it pointless? This would look like the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    Object example1 = object[index].name;
    Object example2 = object2[index].name;
    example1.value1 = example2.value1;
    example1.value2 = example2.value2;
    example1.value3 = example2.value3;
    example1.value4 = example2.value4;
    example1.value5 = example2.value5;
}
```

Would the second example run faster , slower, or the same as the first, and why?

Comment: Why don't you measure the time difference yourself?

Comment: `for (int i…` is not javascript.